# How to determine which livevalidations have failed when a form is submitted

Tags: livevalidation

I'm using LiveValidation in a tall form (so some of the form has scrolled off the top of the screen when the user clicks the submit button at the bottom of the form).

The user may not have visited every field on the form so may not have seen validation failures for "Presence" whilst filling in the form.

If the validation triggered by submitting the form fails, I'd like to determine which fields failed (so that I can set focus to the first field that failed validation so that it is visible to the user).

How can I determine which fields have failed validation? The answer is probably obvious, but it escapes me at the moment.